# Android getItem int GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a custom GridView populated by array of colors. Now when I click the item I want to get the color of cell and pass it. I have this code, but when I click the item, get the result (zero)

```
public class Colori_picker extends Activity {
    private GridView grColori;
    private ColorPickerAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.color_picker);

        grColori = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewColors);
        mAdapter = new ColorPickerAdapter(this);
        grColori.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        grColori.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                int prova = (int) grColori.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
                System.out.println(prova);//here I get 0

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("colore", prova);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

             finish();
        }
    });
}
```

the adapter

```
public class ColorPickerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    private List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int colorGridColumnWidth;
    public ColorPickerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        String colors[][] = {
            { "83334C", "B65775", "E07798", "F7A7C0", "FBC8D9", "FCDEE8" },
            { "000000", "434343", "666666", "999999", "CCCCCC", "EFEFEF" } };

        colorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // add the color array to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < colors[i].length; j++) {
            colorList.add(Color.parseColor("#" + colors[i][j]));
           }
        }
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);


        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setBackgroundColor(colorList.get(position));
        imageView.setId(position);

        return imageView;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return colorList.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting it from the gridview write a public method in the adapter that returns the color from the color array. Something like this should do the trick.

In the adapter put this method.

```
public Integer getSelectedColor(int position) {
    return colorList.get(position);
}
```

Then replace

```
int prova = (int) grColori.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
```

with

```
int prova = (int) mAdapter.getSelectedColor(position);
```

Comment: Thanks, if that helped feel free to upvote and check the it as answered.